# Blue ocean with AWS CodeCommit - how to configure the git access using ssh URL?

Tags: jenkins, aws-codecommit, jenkins-blueocean

I found it very problematic to connect from Jenkins Blue Ocean to AWS CodeCommit git repository using ssh URL, so I will share below the way to do it.

Some more background:
In Blue Ocean you can use either https or ssh URL to connect to git repo. But if you select https version (which works with username+password credentials) then you cannot use some of the BlueOcean features like pipeline editor. So SSH version (which works with private/public key pair) is better.

BlueOcean tries to be nice and generates the keypair for you, you are just asked to upload the public key to the git repo server. This can be done in IAM tool in AWS, but even after that the connection doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Start the create-pipeline wizard in Blue Ocean
- provide ssh repo address let say ssh://codecommiturl/repo
- Jenkins generates key pair and asks you to upload it to git
- do it as described in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html)
- after upload take the value from "SSH Key ID" - this is your username
- go back to Blue Ocean wizard and modify your repo url to be something like this: ssh://username@codecommiturl/repo, where username is equal to "SSH Key ID" from previous step
- Finish creating pipeline

Now you should be able to use Jenkinsfile/pipeline editor from your CI server.

Additional note: for the BlueOcean features to work you need to provide correct Security roles that allow read/write operations on CodeCommit repository.